# Logic puzzle to continue the sequence of symbols?

Tags: puzzle

I encountered a tough logic puzzle, what does the next sequence look like?[image]

Comment: Hint: The four symbols seem to occur in the same *cyclic* order.  From one instance to the next, count the number of quarter rotations needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like every next picture is the previous one rotated clockwise by 1/4 then 2/4, then 3/4... The unknown I expect to be rotated 4/4, i.e. coincide with the last one.